# onchange in apex:inputField for checkbox returning only 1 in javascript function

Tags: apex, visualforce

In my VF page, I'm using onchange in apex:inputField for checkbox, but it's always returning 1 even if I'm unchecking the checkbox.

Based on the checkbox, I need to disable some other inputfields.

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!page2}" value="Next" disabled="{!hasError}" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageMessages />




<apex:outputPanel >

<div id="contactAndAccount">
                    <table>
                        <tr>                        
                            <td colspan="2"><strong>ACCOUNT AND CONTACT INFORMATION</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:outputLabel value="Account Name: " for="accountName" style="color:#ff0000" /></td>
                            <td><apex:inputField id="accountName" value="{!newOppty.AccountId}" /></td>                     
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:outputLabel value="Is FedRAMP Opportunity?: " for="isCheckbox" /> </td>
                            <td><apex:inputField id="isCheckbox" value="{!newOppty.Is_Active__c }" onchange="foo(this);"> 
                                    
                                </apex:inputField> </td>                     
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:outputLabel value="Primary Contact : " for="primaryContact" /></td>
                            <td><apex:inputField id="primaryContact" value="{!tempObject.PrimaryContact__c}" /></td>
                            <td><apex:outputLabel value="Contact Role: " for="primaryConRole" /></td>
                            <td><apex:selectList id="primaryRole" value="{!ocrOpt}" size="1">
                                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!ocrOpts}" />
                                 </apex:selectList>
                             </td>
                        </tr>                       
                    </table>
                </div>

</apex:outputPanel >

</apex:pageBlock >

</apex:form >




<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(data){    
        console.log(' >>> The field value is... '+data.value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `checked`, not `value`:

```
function foo(element) {
  if(element.checked) {
    console.log('The box is checked');
  }
}
```

Also, in the general sense, you should use `event`, rather than `this`.

```
onchange="foo(event)"
```

...

```
function foo(event) {
  if(event.target.checked) {
    console.log('The box is checked');
  }
}
```